# Using Visual Studio to develop MSP430 firmware

Tags: c, visual-studio, msp430, firmware, visualgdb

Hi am migrating a `Code Composer Studio` project to `Visual Studio 2017 (Visual GDB)`

I created a new sample project as explained [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/msp430/) for MCU: **MSP430 FR5729**

Then included(copied) all `.c` and `.h` files to the `Source files` folder in my solution explorer

When I try to build the project I get four errors

> 'interrupt' attribute parameter 96 is out of bounds msp430fr5729
>
> 'interrupt' attribute parameter 86 is out of bounds   msp430fr5729
>
> 'interrupt' attribute requires an integer constant    msp430fr5729
>
> 'interrupt' attribute requires an integer constant    msp430fr5729

I have done similar migration for other MCU **MSP430 F149** and that worked like a charm.

Here is the code segments where it throws errors

> 'interrupt' attribute parameter 96 is out of bounds msp430fr5729

```
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
/**
 * \brief 
 */
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_A0_VECTOR))) USCI_A0_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
```

msp430fr5729.h file contains

```
#define USCI_A0_VECTOR      (0x0060) /* 0xFFF0 USCI A0 Receive/Transmit */
```

> 'interrupt' attribute parameter 86 is out of bounds   msp430fr5729

```
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_A1_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A1_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_A1_VECTOR))) USCI_A1_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
```

msp430fr5729.h file contains

```
#define USCI_A1_VECTOR      (0x0056) /* 0xFFE6 USCI A1 Receive/Transmit */
```

> 'interrupt' attribute requires an integer constant    msp430fr5729

```
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A0 (void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(TIMER_A0_VECTOR))) Timer_A0 (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
```

msp430fr5729.h does not contain **TIMER_A0_VECTOR** defined

> 'interrupt' attribute requires an integer constant    msp430fr5729

```
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=TIMER1_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer1_A0 (void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(TIMER_A0_VECTOR))) Timer1_A0 (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
```

msp430fr5729.h does not contain **TIMER_A0_VECTOR** defined

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Version Info for `msp430fr5729.h`

```
/********************************************************************
*
* Standard register and bit definitions for the Texas Instruments
* MSP430 microcontroller.
*
* This file supports assembler and C development for
* MSP430FR5729 devices.
*
* Texas Instruments, Version 1.23
*
* Rev. 1.0, Setup
* Rev. 1.1  Fixed definition of RTCTEV__0000 and RTCTEV__1200
*           Removed not availabe bits RTCMODE and RTCSSELx
*           Added PxSELC registers
* Rev. 1.2  Removed Port Drive Strenght Registers
* Rev. 1.3  updated PxSELC register address to offset 0x16 (instead of 0x10)
*
********************************************************************/
```

Comment: `USCI_A0_VECTOR` should have the value 49. What is the version of your `msp430fr5729.h` file?

Comment: @CL.I think its Version 1.23, updated the question with header info

Comment: That's the same version I have. And what is the value of `USCI_A0_VECTOR` (at the bottom)?

Comment: @CL.#define USCI_A0_VECTOR      (0x0060) /* 0xFFF0 USCI A0 Receive/Transmit */

Comment: @CL.its actually failing at 4 incidents for USCI_A0_VECTOR, USCI_A1_VECTOR and TIMER_A0_VECTOR, updated the question with all details

Comment: There are different .h files for the different compilers. Did you copy the fr5729.h from the old project?

Comment: @CL I copied it. Now #define USCI_A0_VECTOR  (49) but still error interrupt' attribute parameter 49 is out of bounds msp430fr5729

Comment: Throw away all old files you did not write yourself; the new compiler should already have them.